# How to use Sql connection inside another connection?

Tags: c#, database-connection, sqlconnection

I faced some problem about sql connection issue. The problem is I have some code like this

```
function1()
{
    using (sqlconnection sc = new sqlconnection())
   {
      foo();
   }
}

foo is a function like below:
foo()
{
   using (sqlconnection sc = new sqlconnection())
  {
        dosomething;
  }
}
```

It seems that the sqlconnection in foo() cannot work. I'm wondering if it is a good idea to pass the sqlconnection into foo like foo(sc), or is it a good idea to take foo outside function1, or is there anyway to allow the sqlconnection inside foo works.

Comment: Without more specifics we can't really say. Are they trying to connect to the same server? Why do you need the connection in `function1` if all it's doing is calling another method?

Comment: A connection is a session. Sessions are separate. In essence if you use a sqlcommand you tie it to a connection. Within one connection you can use only a single sqlreader, unless you enable mars. Multiple result sets. In short what you are trying should work, if it does not there is a different issue. You should show more code and real errors or exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

No need of that, have your function `foo` to accepts a connection parameter and use the same connection instance in both places like below

```
function1()
{
    using (sqlconnection sc = new sqlconnection())
   {
      foo(sc);
   }
}

foo is a function like below:

foo(sqlconnection scc)
{
    sqlconnection sc = scc
    dosomething;
}
```

Comment: seems a good idea, will sc inside foo affect sc inside function1? Since it is a connection, I don't know if it is a "copy" of sc inside function1 like other "virtual" object is.

Comment: @litaoshen, Yes it will since it's a reference type and not a value type but the sole idea is to use the same connection object instead having multiple one. You can use the same con object and can have different command object or same to that matter.

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you!